# How can i split an Audio file into multiple audio wav files from folder

Tags: python, audio, wav, pydub

I have a folder where i have about 2000 audio files in wav format with different time intervals, say some are in 30 sec some 40 and i want to split all of them using python, i tried pydub and different libraries and all of them working for 1 file only, i want to split those using a loop with simple code in python.

### Sample code:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment 
from pydub.utils import make_chunks 

myaudio = AudioSegment.from_file("a0007.wav", "wav") 
chunk_length_ms = 8000 # pydub calculates in millisec 
chunks = make_chunks(myaudio,chunk_length_ms) #Make chunks of one sec 
for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks): 
    chunk_name = "{0}.wav".format(i) 
    print ("exporting", chunk_name) 
    chunk.export(chunk_name, format="wav")
```

The above code is working for one file whereas i need it to take files from folder and split all of them

Comment: Can you share your folder structure and the code you tried?

Comment: from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import make_chunks

myaudio = AudioSegment.from_file("a0007.wav", "wav") 

chunk_length_ms = 8000 # pydub calculates in millisec

chunks = make_chunks(myaudio,chunk_length_ms) #Make chunks of one sec

for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
    chunk_name = "{0}.wav".format(i)
    print ("exporting", chunk_name)
    chunk.export(chunk_name, format="wav")

The above code is working for one file whereas i need it to take files from folder and split all of them

Comment: Please modify your question to add the code. It is not readable in the comment.

Comment: @Epsi95 it is Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get all the file names in your directory and then iterate for all file names.

You can use `os` module to get list of all the files in the current directory.

```py
from pydub import AudioSegment 
from pydub.utils import make_chunks
import os

def process_sudio(file_name):
    myaudio = AudioSegment.from_file(file_name, "wav") 
    chunk_length_ms = 8000 # pydub calculates in millisec 
    chunks = make_chunks(myaudio,chunk_length_ms) #Make chunks of one sec 
    for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks): 
        chunk_name = './chunked/' + file_name + "_{0}.wav".format(i) 
        print ("exporting", chunk_name) 
        chunk.export(chunk_name, format="wav") 

all_file_names = os.listdir()
try:
    os.makedirs('chunked') # creating a folder named chunked
except:
    pass
for each_file in all_file_names:
    if ('.wav' in each_file):
        process_sudio(each_file)
```

Comment: Well its only splitting the first file and giving error on 2nd file and not picking up any other files.
Its giving the following error
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'a0002.wav'

Comment: do you have your python script in the folder where all your audio file exists? Does this folder has this file `a0002.wav`.

Comment: I have modified the code, the chunked file will be stored in another folder named chunked.

Comment: The script is in the same folder and that contain all of the files however it is picking up only first file

Comment: Can you check now, I ran on my computer and it is working fine.

Comment: Working perfect, Thank you :)